Agents not moving or getting stuck in nothing with AI Navmesh Unity 6
I spawn agents on my nav mesh and then set their destination to a point in an array of points. The spawning of the minions looks like this:
private void CreateMinion(PlayerNumber player, UnitSO unitData)
{
    Transform[] pathPoints = GetCurrentPlayerPaths((int)player);
    Transform spawn = player == PlayerNumber.Player1 ? P1CreepsSpawn : P2CreepsSpawn;
    GameObject newMinion = Instantiate(unitPrefab, new Vector3(pathPoints[0].position.x, spawn.position.y), Quaternion.identity);
    newMinion.GetComponent<Unit>().minionAttributes = unitData;
    newMinion.GetComponent<Unit>().player = (int)player;
    newMinion.GetComponent<Unit>().playerPath = pathPoints;
    newMinion.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().Spawn(true);
}

Then OnNetworkSpawn on the minions, I do this:
agent.updateRotation = false;
agent.updateUpAxis = false;
agent.speed = minionAttributes.MoveSpeed;

if (NavMesh.SamplePosition(playerPath[pointIndex].position, out NavMeshHit hit, 0.25f, NavMesh.AllAreas))
{
    Debug.Log($"NAV HIT BABY: {hit.position}");
    NavMeshPath path = new NavMeshPath();
    bool yep = agent.CalculatePath(hit.position, path);
    Debug.Log($"Path: {path.status} ({yep})");
    agent.SetDestination(hit.position);
}

And here's what it looks like when they spawn, and I set their destination (I Debug.DrawLine their path in red):
https://gyazo.com/4454aa2018fe86dfca049ec6523bb344
https://gyazo.com/b83f8991a0bd773c97fd5cb7a869ce38
Also if the movement is not vertical it seems to be fine for some odd reason:
https://gyazo.com/ef588d9579f8c85fedc6377c0335f2c2
As soon as they get into vertical movment sometimes they get stuck on I don't know what...
If you need more specifications, let me know. I am using the NavMesh Plus Components.
Thanks in advance :slight_smile:

navmesh plus? not the unity AI navigation packages?

@BugFinder Its a mix of both, that package gives the opportunity to work with AI Nav in 2d and with Tilemaps but I found the fix I will comment it right now

I fixed my problem by reading thoroughly the Navmesh Plus's Github to figure out that the agents have some problems moving on the Y axis, and you have to tilt your navmesh a bit on the X axis to get it to work properly as mentioned in the known issues...

Thanks this solved my issue! A note that in the latest NavMesh Plus, there is a "Tilt Surface" button under the Navigation CollectSource2d component. You can click on it and the plugin will do the correct job for you.
